# Azure Service Bus Alternatives

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We continue to see instability in Azure Service Bus and are looking for alternatives. Ideally we would like something we can run locally in a Windows 2012 R2 domain and has many of the same feature sets as Azure SB. We have taken a look at the Service Bus For Windows 1.1 however that product has not been updated in a while and we are not sure about its future. We use C# so ideally there would be a client API/wrapper that would make the integration with our existing application relatively easy. Open source and free software is totally acceptable. :-)

Background
In the couple of weeks we have had SB go down in the datacenter we have chosen to host our queues. We have moved to another datacenter and it too has issues every once in a while. The issues typically last anywhere from 2 min to almost an entire day and eventually Microsoft gets them running again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend exploring [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) with [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) as an API, or [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/nservicebus) (which is commercial)

RabbitMQ is a message broker that supports multiple transport layers (such as HTTP, AMQP, and STOMP among others) has feature parity with Azure service bus, however it is not cloud based, and you will need to host it on some infrastructure and support it, but it is robust and supports clustering and federation.

RabbitMQ is open source. Both free and commercial versions available. Has paid support.

Comment: Has anyone looked at EventGrid as an alternative?